# Running AngularJS / Jasmine tests on build or source version of a project

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine

I'm building a project with the help of AngularJS with multiple apps in one projects sharing components / modules. I also have a Grunt build task to "optimize" the sources to a bundled version.

So the question is: Should I run my tests in Jasmine for an AngularJS project on the orginal sources or the builded version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would see two points now after working a while within the project:

- unit testing: on original source files in respect to code coverage and testing small pieces
- end 2 end testing: build version, to check the functionality of the built product

Answer (score 0):

Main idea behind E2E testing is be as close as real user as you can. 
So I say builded version, because that is what you will be deploying on production.

Comment: Sorry - I'm thinking about the unit tests, not the E2E tests.

Comment: Ah, ok :), then it imho shouldn`t matter that much, but Testing closest to production is imho generally a good idea.

Comment: But is it the task of the unit tests to test the influence of minification or should they test the source of the project. Do the unit tests still run after uglyfication?

Comment: Task of unit tests is to verify single code unit works as expected, minification/uglyfication shouldn`t affect it.

Comment: Shouldn't (and probably won't) but it's included in testing of the build sources, like all of the other build steps. But thank you for your oppionon - I'll consider the arguments.